# KB3060716 Fails to install, prevents me from upgrading to windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

Every time I try to update to windows 10, it stops me about failed updates.

I've tried safe mode with networking, running various tools like jrt, I've ran the update readiness tool (~500 MB).  I've deleted the update history so it would re-detect updates.

I'm wondering if my junction points of some non system files might be causing the update to fail.  My user has an ssd and files on the c:.  So I moved some big files to this larger m:.  One was sony sonicstage which had files in c:\programdata.

I know from past experience, having user folders as junction points prevented .net from installing.  Wondering if something similar is going on here.

I've also tried deleting the old updates from the Downloads folder as suggested online, and I've also ran sfc /scannow which found no errors.

Any ideas?

I figured the best I could do is remove the junction points?  However many I have and/or do a clean install of windows 10.

Edits:

Running Windows 7 x64 Home Premium

Error: check your pc before upgrading before installing windows 10 insider preview, something needs your attention

Then shows me the list of recent attempted updates, with the one holding me up being the one mentioned here

Comment: What happens if you download the .iSO, create a bootable disk, and run the installer from within your current version of Windows?  Does it fail then?  Your existing version of Windows is what exactly?  **Edit** your question to include that information.

Comment: What error do you receive when the update fails to install?  Knowing what error can help understand, the reason, the update is failing.

Comment: Why are you attempting to install Windows 10 Insider Preview?  Windows naively uses junction points you don't want to get rid of all of them, only the ones that cause a conflict, in other words the ones you created yourself.

Comment: I have no idea why I'm trying to install insider preview.  That's what it attempts to install when I attempt a windows 10 upgrade.

Comment: So answer my very question I asked you in my first comment that has remained unanswered as of yet.  The fact you are attempting to install the `Windows 10 Insider Preview` indicates your machine has not installed any updates for over 12 months.

Comment: No need to be pushy.  This is a customers machine.  It is not my personal machine.  I received it and figured I'd try to push windows 10, which was the insider preview, of which I did answer you already.  That's what it's trying to push.  Now that I see it's pushing an old version of windows 10, I looked into it, and it might be related to update kb2990214, which may need to be removed.  If that doesn't work, I'll try what you also suggested, trying the iso, and try an update that way.  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: The update will continue to fail because the Insider Preview build your attempting to download, has long expired, so even if it were successful you wouldn't put the machine in a state where the only recourse would be to format the machine and install Windows again.  Since you cannot provide us with the information, about if Windows 10 upgrade process is successful if done another way, I will just walk away.

Comment: "Since you cannot provide us with the information, about if Windows 10 upgrade process is successful if done another way, I will just walk away" I can't at this moment, because I'm asking while I'm at work.  I will try your suggestions when I get home and post whether one of your two suggestions worked.

Answer (score 0):

Following Ramhound's suggestion

I uninstalled update kb2990214
Ran GWX control panel utility using it to remove various windows 10 items.
Downloaded the liveUSB installer (vs trying to update through windows update), and ran the upgrade from that (as in from within windows, I ran setup.exe).  Voila, got Windows 10.